# How to convert a Riemann sum to a definite

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, summation

I want to convert $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \arctan\left(1 + \frac{2}{n} k\right) \,\frac{1}{n}.$$ to a definite integral.

I know this:
$$\int_{x=a}^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n} k\right) \frac{b-a}{n}.$$

but I don't know how to match them, since in the summation, first I have 1/n, and then 2/n*k; they don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \underbrace{arctan}_{f(x)}(\underbrace{1 + \frac{2}{n} k}_{ \text{arguement of the function}}) \frac{1}{n}
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that when $k=0$  we get $a=1$ and when $k=n$, $b-a=2$ so $b=3$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \arctan(1 + \frac{2}{n} k) \frac{1}{\color{red}{2}} \frac{\color{red}{2}}{n} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\int_1^3 \tan^{-1}(x) \mathrm{dx}.
\end{eqnarray*}